# Trouble positioning elements using float in a responsive design

Tags: html, css, css-float, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm working on a responsive website, and I ran into some trouble doing the layout. I broke the problem down to the fewest lines possible.

When the window is larger then 909px I want to place my second content (content2) just below the title. When there is less space availible I want it to be placed below the image.

Currently it always gets placed below the image.

[Here](http://www.imagebanana.com/view/t1dhsq0h/draft.png)'s a visual.

I need to find a solution without using absolute positioning, because the title does not have a fixed height. In fact none of my html elements have a fixed height, I do have fixed widths though.

I have been trying to come up with a simple solution for a few hours now. Here's hoping someone can point me in the right direction :)

Thanks for reading!

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1> some title </h1>
  <div class="image"> some img</div>
  <div class="content1"> some content </div>
  <div class="content2"> some other content </div>
</div>
```

**CSS styles:**

```
.content1{
  float: left;
}
.image{
  width: 600px;
}
.content2{
  width: 300px;
  float: right;
}

@screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 909px){
  .wrapper {
    width: 700px;
  }
  .content1 {
    width: 300px;
  }
}

@screen and (min-width: 909px){
  .wrapper {
    width: 900px;
  }
  .content1{
    width: 600px;
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't 2005. Stop using floats for your layouts.

Comment: @AlexW - What's wrong with using floats?

Comment: @j08691 He's using it to layout block elements, which could easily be done with inline-block without the need for clearfixes, etc.

Comment: I assume that the `id` attributes should really be `class` in your HTML ...

Comment: http://designshack.net/articles/css/farewell-floats-the-future-of-css-layout/

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/give-floats-the-flick-in-css-layouts/

Comment: @Marc Audet You assumed correctly. I just edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it for the case of `min-width: 909px`

The CSS is:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 909px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 900px;
        outline: 1px dotted blue; /* optional for demo */
    }
    .image {
        width: 600px;
        float: left;
        outline: 1px dotted blue; /* optional for demo */
    }
    .content1 {
        float: left;
        width: 600px;
        outline: 1px dotted blue; /* optional for demo */
    }
    .content2 {
        width: 300px;
        margin-left: 600px;
        outline: 1px dotted blue; /* optional for demo */
    }
}
```

and the demo fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/WfyJL/

I did not see anything about heights, so I assume that the content will take determine the various heights of the elements.

**How This Works**

In your previous example, `content2` is floated so its top edge is placed next to the bottom edge of the nearest, adjacent block level element, which is `image`.

To get the desired layout for the 900px format, float `image` to the left, and keep `content2` in the flow but with a 600px left margin to allow the left floated elements to flow down the left hand side of `content2`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need use some like this, with offsets, hope your help

```
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
          <h1> some title </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
          <div id="image"> some img</div>
          <div id="content1"> some content </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span8 offset5">
          <div id="content2"> some other content </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: oh, my mistake, im thinking you are using bootstrap